# Swift and Boolean

Tags: core-audio, swift

The function AUGraphIsInitialized is defined like this:

```
func AUGraphIsInitialized(inGraph: AUGraph, outIsInitialized: CMutablePointer<Boolean>) -> OSStatus
```

So, you call it like this:

```
var status : OSStatus = OSStatus(noErr)
var outIsInitialized:Boolean = 0
status = AUGraphIsInitialized(self.processingGraph, &outIsInitialized)
```

That works. But how do you check it?

Boolean is defined as an CUnsignedChar (in MacTypes.h)

So, you cannot do this:

```
if outIsInitialized {
    // whatever
}
```

And you cannot cast it (could not find an overload...)

```
var b:Bool = Bool(outIsInitialized)
```

or with Swift's "as"

```
var b:Bool = outIsInitialized as Bool
```

So, my question is: how do you use Boolean in Swift?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C represents the Boolean value true with a nonzero value and false with a zero value, so you can just test `outIsInitialized` against `0`:

```
if outIsInitialized != 0 {
    // outIsInitialized is true
}
```

Comment: Lol, me too, I've deleted my response.  Good show @nathan.

Comment: No shame, @BryanMcLemore. We're all learning. Playing with core audio via Swift is a great way to nail down your understanding of types.