# Test FTP connection using CFReadStreamCreateWithFTPURL in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, ftp, swift

I am using the following code to try to test an FTP connection:

```
func OpenAndTestFTPConn(user:NSString, pass:NSString) -> Bool {

    var ftpstring = "ftp://\(user):\(pass)@\(txtTarget.stringValue)"
    var ftpNSURL = NSURL(string: ftpstring)
    var FTPStream = CFReadStreamCreateWithFTPURL(nil, ftpNSURL)
    var status:Bool
    var cfstatus:Boolean = CFReadStreamOpen(FTPStream) as Boolean
    if cfstatus == 0 {
        status = false
    }
    else {
        status = true
    }
    println(status)
    return status

}
```

When I try building this, the line `var cfstatus:Boolean = CFReadStreamOpen(FTPStream) as Boolean` returns the error `Cannot convert the expression's type 'Boolean' to type 'CFReadStream!'`. If I remove the type declarations on both sides of the expression, the error returned is `Cannot convert the expression's type 'Boolean' to type '$T3'`.

Where am I going wrong?

*Note: the `cstatus` definition and statements are based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109034/swift-and-boolean).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CFReadStreamCreateWithFTPURL` method returns an `Unmanaged<CFReadStream>` (per the docs), meaning that this particular function doesn't yet have Swift-compatible annotations indicating whether returned values have been retained or not. For more details, see "Unmanaged Objects" in [this section of the Swift book](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html).

For me, this code doesn't compile past the `CFReadStreamCreateWithFTPURL` call because of this issue. I don't see the Boolean error; it's strange that you're seeing that error and no error on the `CFReadStreamCreateWithFTPURL` call. Are you on Beta3?

I was able to get the code to compile with:

```
let FTPStream = CFReadStreamCreateWithFTPURL(nil, ftpNSURL).takeRetainedValue()
```

which converts the unmanaged value to an ARC-compatible pointer by asserting that the function has already retained the value (again, per its docs).

BTW, it's a nitpick, but all of your `var`'s can be `let`'s.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. And I'm on Beta2 (build 6A216f).

Comment: @Matt Glad to hear it!