# FTP Connection Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ftp

I'm actually trying to connect my iOS App to a ftp server.

First of all I would like to test the connection.

I found a good example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718378/test-ftp-connection-using-cfreadstreamcreatewithftpurl-in-swift)

Below my code :

```
    let ftpUrl = NSURL(string: "ftp://user:pass@myaddress.com")

    let stream = CFReadStreamCreateWithFTPURL(nil, ftpUrl).takeUnretainedValue()

    var cfstatus:Boolean = CFReadStreamOpen(stream) as Boolean

    if cfstatus == 0 {
        statusLabel.text = "Not connected"
    }
    else {
        statusLabel.text = "Connected"
    }
```

The problem is that I always return "Connected" even if I enter wrong login/password...

Any idea?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I would use libcurl instead. Much more straightforward than trying to translate the Objective-C wrapper to Swift.